# Global includes file

Tags: php

I'm calling in a global.inc.php file (and two others (header/footer)) but getting back a plain white/blank page.

Normally I use this on the root level of the domain but in this case I am doing some amends within a new sub directory (/development), and have therefore taken this into account (correctly I hope) don't see what's going on. The index has some simple hello world text.

Starting off with my index.php is:

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Manage/_includes/global.inc.php';?>
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Manage/_includes/header.php';
?>

    <p>Hello World</p>
```

and within that global.inc.php file the associated code is:

```
// settings
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/development');
define('HTTP_HOST','http://www.example.com/development');
define('EMAIL_DOMAIN', 'example.com/development');

// settings
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .= '/development/';
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'http://example.com/development';

//$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].='/';
$DOMAIN_INFO = "http://example.com/development";
```

I've hidden my domain.

Comment: Could you attach the code of your header aswell?

Comment: All that file has is the doctype, head meta etc, and navigation menu.

Comment: Hello, you include `global.inc.php` using a variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` that you set only in `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`: do you think it's correct/expected? Another curiosity: why do you write the `$_SERVER[]` array?